# How to speedup RegionIntersection?

Tags: performance-tuning, regions, geometry, intersection

Consider a circle `circle` located at the origin of a coordinate frame and with a radius `ROffAxisArb` (it is parametrized by two coordinates z, $\theta$), and some rectangle `rectangle`:

```
ROffAxisArb[th_, z_] = z*Tan[th];
circle[z_, th_] = 
  Circle[{0, 0}, ROffAxisArb[th, z]];

rectangle = Rectangle[{-1.25, 1.}, {1.25, 3.5}];
```

I would like to compute the region of the intersection of these figures:

```
intersection[zN_, thN_] = 
 RegionIntersection[rectangle, circle[zN, thN]]
```

However, it turns out that this is relatively slow:

```
intersection[20,0.06]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0144315, Circle[{0., 0.}, 1.20144, {0.983304, 2.15829}]}

Could you please tell me whether it is possible to speedup this function?

Comment: seems that rectangle with rational coordinates ( `rectangle = 
 Rectangle[Rationalize@{-1.25, 1.}, Rationalize@{1.25, 3.5}]`) makes it somewhat faster.

Comment: @kglr : in my case, no speedup occurred.